# How can I connect a Raspberry Pi 3+ with a MacBook Pro 2018?

Tags: pi-3, ssh, ethernet, connection, macos

I would like to access my Raspberry Pi via SSH and am not sure how to connect it to my MacBook Pro from 2018, given that it only has USB-C ports.

**My idea was to buy a crossover Ethernet cable and an Ethernet to USB-C adaptor from Amazon.** Do you guys think this will work? I am having doubts that the adaptor may override the crossover functionality of the Ethernet cable. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Is there no wifi available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to worry about a crossover ethernet cable. That's a requirement from the last century. Nowadays nearly all ethernet ports have crossover auto detect built-in. You only need one port supporting this and the wired port of the Raspberry Pi do it. So just purchase a proper wired ethernet dongle for the MacBook Pro and use any ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your ssh porting first, Then install something on your mac that let you use ssh. Connect your raspberry p and mac in same router and connect them wit the IP of pi.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apple problem, to use Ethernet you have to purchase an adapter. Indeed the new MacBooks need a fistful of dongles to do anything except connect to WiFi, although this is also the case with many modern notebooks.

If you connect the WiFi on both MacBook and Pi to your router you will have ssh access. You can use Ethernet on the Pi to connect your router, which should work without any configuration (you need to tell the Pi to enable ssh by creating a file called ssh on the SD Card).

NOTE the Pi is designed to be used in a normal network i.e. connected to a router. If you directly connect to a computer it will not have Internet access.

PS forget crossover cables. Gigabit Ethernet needs a 8 wire CAT5/6 cable.